# Ad module. Channel URL's being ignored

Tags: advertising

I have a site using just the default ad "group: default" block and am using channels to place ads on certain URLs

The block seems to follow these rules but I have one advert in a channel that appears all over the place and ignores the rules set up for the channel it sits in.

Is this a bug in the system or something that is not set up right in terms of weights/priorities.

Non of my channels are associated with any groups, would this cause a problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.